# SQL increment counter that resets on zero - Optimization?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains consecutive dates and integers.

My goal is to add a counter that increments as each integer is zero and resets back to 1 if the integer is non-zero.
I'm hoping that this can be optimized a bit as it can be an expensive query when run on the entire table.

Below is the code that is working. Thanks to everyone that takes a look.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
( 
                    d DATE, 
                    n INT
)

INSERT INTO @test
VALUES
       ('2021-01-01', 0),
       ('2021-01-02', 0),
       ('2021-01-03', 0),
       ('2021-01-04', 5),
       ('2021-01-05', 0),
       ('2021-01-06', 0),
       ('2021-01-07', 10),
       ('2021-01-08', 10),
       ('2021-01-09', 0),
       ('2021-01-10', 0),
       ('2021-01-11', 9),
       ('2021-01-12', 0),
       ('2021-01-13', 0)

SELECT *
FROM   @test;

WITH test1
     AS (SELECT t1.d, 
                t1.n,
                CASE
                    WHEN t1.n = 0 THEN ( SELECT MAX(d)
                                         FROM  @test t2
                                         WHERE t2.d < t1.d
                                               AND t2.n <> 0 )
                    ELSE t1.d
                END AS 'dateFlag'
         FROM @test AS t1)
     SELECT d, 
            n, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dateFlag
            ORDER BY d ASC)
     FROM   test1
     ORDER BY d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, hat's off to @Charlieface for the spot-on answer.  I voted his answer up, as well.

Since @mrplow (the OP) is concerned with performance, let's have a little fun and do some tests for the other type of performance... **Resource Usage**.  To do that, we need a lot more rows of data.  The following builds a Temp Table with a lot more data.  Details are in the comments.

```
--===== This creates a 3,012,154 row table containing every date in the DATETIME
     -- datatype range similar to the smaller original posted by the OP.
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test
;
   WITH cteDenDate AS
(
 SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101','99991231')+1)
        d = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID)-1,'17530101'))
   FROM sys.all_columns ac1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns ac2 --Nasty Fast "Pseudo-Cursor RowSource"
)
 SELECT d,n = IIF(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%5) > 0,0,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%10)+1)
   INTO #Test
   FROM cteDenDate
;
```

I first tried @mrplow 's code (just changed the @test to #test in the code).  He was right to be concerned with performance.  It drove all 12 logical processors on my laptop to 100% and stayed there.  I stopped the run after a minute.

Then I tried @Charlieface 's code.  As expected, it ran quite nicely. I made two changes to his code. One was to change @test to #test. The other was to direct the output to a #Result Temp Table just to take the display time (a long time) out of the picture. Then I wrapped it in SET STATISTICS pairs to measure performance and resource usage.

Here's what I ended up using for testing his good code.

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Result;
    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO ON;
WITH Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
        GroupId = COUNT(CASE WHEN n <> 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY d ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM #test
)
SELECT
  d,
  n,
  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY d)
INTO #Result
FROM Groupings;
    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO OFF;
```

As expected, that ran in a hurry.  Here are the statistics on the run.

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 6721, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#Test_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000033'. 
Scan count 13, logical reads 5953, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 7923 ms,  elapsed time = 3096 ms.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(3012154 rows affected)
```

I visually spot checked several sections of the #Result table and the code works exactly as desired/expected.

Since we're talking performance, I noticed the "Scan count" (parallelism). All 12 logical processors came into play and that's the reason why the total CPU time was longer than the elapsed time.  Since @mrplow was concerned about performance (and I'm also always concerned with resource usage), I decided to see what kind of a tradeoff we'd get with just 1 logical processor.  Here's the code for that.  The only change is the OPTION (MAXDOP 1) that I added.

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Result;
    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO ON;
WITH Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
        GroupId = COUNT(CASE WHEN n <> 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY d ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM #test
)
SELECT
  d,
  n,
  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY d)
INTO #Result
FROM Groupings
OPTION (MAXDOP 1); --<---<<<< Added this
    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO OFF;
```

Here are the statistics from that.

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 6710, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#Test_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000033'. 
Scan count 1, logical reads 5953, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 3891 ms,  elapsed time = 3935 ms.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(3012154 rows affected)
```

As percentages, the elapsed time increased by a whopping 27% but isn't real noticeable by human perception.  However, the number of logical CPU's used was just 1 leaving the other 11 wide open for other processes and the total CPU time decreased by 49%.  Using only 1 CPU instead of 12 and using 49% less CPU is a pretty good win.

Going one step further, I tried a little trick with the SIGN() function because it fits the idea of only counting only positive values in the face of only zeros and positive values.  You can read about the function at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Here's the code with the OPTION (MAXDOP 1) in place.

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Result;
    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO ON;

   WITH cteGrp AS
(--==== Count number of values of "n" over zero
 SELECT *,Grp = SUM(SIGN(N)) OVER (ORDER BY d ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
   FROM #Test
)--==== Create sequences starting at the first row and restart at 1 when n>0
 SELECT d,n,Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY d)
   INTO #Result
   FROM cteGrp
  ORDER BY d
 OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO OFF;
```

After spot checking the #Result table to make sure that, too, came up with the correct values, I ran it with and without the OPTION (MAXDOP 1) with similar results.  The ONLY difference is that the code is a tiny bit simpler.

Actually, there was one additional difference.  It got rid of the following message.  You could do the same in @Charlieface 's code by changing his COUNT() to a SUM() and adding an ELSE 0 to his CASE statement.

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

As a final performance related sidebar, the ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING that @Charlieface used is absolutely necessary for performance in all the code (I wish that MS would have just up and defaulted to that).  Without it, the duration and CPU usage increases by a factor of 5 and the memory I/O in the form of a working table goes absolutely bonkers.

Here are the statistics without the ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING.  The scan count and logical reads on the work table are absolutely nuts!

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3012155, logical reads 26541692, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 6710, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#Test_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000033'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5953, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 19406 ms,  elapsed time = 19415 ms.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(3012154 rows affected)
```

Lordy. That turned out to be kinda long, didn't it?  I hope it helps even though a lot of it has nothing to do with the original question. :D

Answer (score 3):

**This is a type of *gaps-and-islands* problem.**

There are many solutions, here is one

- Use a running conditional count to get an ID for each island
- Genrate a row number partitioned by that ID

```sql
WITH Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
        GroupId = COUNT(CASE WHEN n <> 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY d ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM @test
)
SELECT
  d,
  n,
  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY d)
FROM Groupings;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7ec53bcae8a29615648dd50a32c09b6b)

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, lots of info on the interwebs now that I know the gaps and Islands term.